# How to run Romex cable to Enphase Combiner box 3?

Tags: electrical, wiring, solar

In designing in the solar panels, I've decided to run the wire inside of the house.  So far, I am running 10/2 Romex from the attic all the way to the Enphase Combiner Box surface mounted on the outside.

What I can't figure out is how to connect the Romex into the combiner box, since local permit office is telling me that I can't run Romex in conduit.  And without a conduit, how can I go from inside of the house through exterior wall into the surface mount combiner box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is run your Romex as planned to a junction box on the inside wall and run conduit from the junction box through the wall to your combiner box. Splice your 10/2 Romex to #10 AWG THHN single conductors with wire nuts and run the THHN in the conduit to your combiner box. That should keep everyone happy.

Comment: Thank you!  Or I was thinking about a crazy alternative, instead of surface mount the combiner box, I can flush mount the combiner box and run Romex (NM-B) in it.  Does that work at all?

Comment: If you flush mount it on the outside wall, it's still considered an outdoor fixture and you'd need UF cable. You can run the entire length using UF.

Comment: Thanks! I thought flush mount would solve my problem, since my main panel is flush mounted right next to it and has NM-B (I think?!) running into it.  So this brings me to another question. Why is main panel okay to have NM-B running to it? Or did I make a mistake and those aren't NM-B cables into the main breaker panel?

Comment: Does your main panel open from the outside. If the location has any chance of water or moisture, the cable 's supposed to be UF.

Comment: yes, my main panel opens from the outside. and I'm pretty sure it's NM-B cables running to it, since I see paper sheathing.  This is weird! The house was built in 2003, and you'd think they have it up to code?

Comment: Is it a weatherproof panel?  I do believe there is some grey area in this and the inspectors have some "say" in the matter,  what's weatherproof, what's not.   Does your solar panel installation need to be inspected???

Comment: I see... I don't know about the panel, but I do know that the combiner box is NEMA 3R rated. And yes, my solar panel installation will need to be inspected.  I am in the sunny California. Heh. Anyway, thanks, this has been an interesting thread. Learned a lot! I'll communicate with the inspection office, and worst comes to worst, I'll just do what you said. JBox then THHN to the Combiner Box.

Answer (score 1):

"Romex" is a brand name, not a type.  But generally people mean NM-B when they say that.

They meant you can't run "Romex" outdoors in conduit.  It's technically possible to run indoor Romex (NM-B) in conduit, though the conduit tends to be bulky for the size due to the oval shape of the wire.  It's treated as a round wire of the larger dimension.

They do make something you'd recognize as "Romex" that is rated for outdoors; that is called UF-B.  However it's much thinner and wider than normal NM-B, and that means it requires much larger conduit - that's often seen as impractical.

So you are trapped between two forces: the limitations of "Romex" in outdoor conduit, vs... the limits of your knowledge.

If this old dog is willing to learn new tricks, we can tell you about THHN wire (technically we need THWN-2, outdoor rated, but almost all THHN made is dual-rated THWN-2.) These are individual wires with no sheath, similar to what's inside Romex, but with markings and a nylon outer coating for slickness.  They are very easy to work with (buy stranded!) but absolutely require a conduit around them for physical protection.

As Jack discusses, you can transition from THHN to Romex in any junction box that remains accessible.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know most THHN wire are dual-rated for THWN-2 too.